# Shorthand for `v-bind` in case when child component property name equals passed object name

Tags: vue.js

Are there (in Vue) any shorthand for `v-bind` in case when child component property name equals passed object name? I mean shorthand for `:prop="prop"` part of this code:

```
<component :prop="prop"></component>
```

I tried this:

```
<component :prop></component>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know there is not such a shorthand.

Comment: it is sadly. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no shorthand in Vue for that.

But, you can pass an object to `v-bind` and use the [ES2015 property name shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
<component v-bind="{ prop }"></component>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in vue 3.4+

[From the docs:](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#same-name-shorthand)

```html
<!-- same as :id="id" -->
<div :id></div>

<!-- this also works -->
<div v-bind:id></div>
```